# How to Translate contour to the center of image in openCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am working on an image processing project in android. Currently my task is to extract the object and translate it to the center of the image so that i can extract features from it easily.
I have extracted the object, Now i want to translate it to the center of image and rotate it, to align it horizontally on the image.

I am using OpenCV for image processing in Android. 
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest following technique..

`vector<point>contour` -- opencv contours are vector of points. so you can translate them by the distance you want. So in c++ i would do the following to translate the contour

```
void shifcontour(vector<Point>& contour, int x, int y)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<contour.size(); i++)
    {
        contour[i].x += x;
        contour[i].y += y;
    }
}
```

to find xand y,  you can use the difference between the centre of the image and centre of the contour. you can use fitEllipse to calculate centre of the contour. that will give you rough approximation to the  centre of your contour. also you will get the angle in which  contour is directed..

```
(x_centre,y_centre),(majoraxis,minoraxis),angle = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
```

Now your contour is being translated. next you have to rotate it, to align it horizontally. you can use affine tranformation provided by opencv to rotate the image by specified angle.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

Hope this helps.