# Rotate area to align the major axis horizontally with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, axis

Please can someone here who can help me with this. I'm trying to rotate a segmented region of an image to align the major axis horizontally.
I have a segmented region in the center of the image following the steps used herein. [Move area of an image to the center using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590277/move-area-of-an-image-to-the-center-using-opencv/32593934#32593934)
I read this [OPENCV: PCA application error in image_proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731368/opencv-pca-application-error-in-image-proc/21735828#21735828), but it does not help me solve my problem.
I have this

[image]

I want this

[image]

Comment: Post an example image, and expected result. You should be able to do that using a combination of `findNonZero`, `minAreaRect` and `rotate`.

Comment: Attached Images, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different than how Miki suggested, I used findNonZero, minAreaRect, and WarpAffine.

You can either use 270 or 90 on the getRotationMatrix2D to align the major axis with the horizontal.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv2\core\mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main() {

    //getting the image
    Mat image = imread("C:/this/is/a/path/to/an/image.png");

    //create new image that looks exactly like old image
    Mat rot_image = image.clone();
    rot_image = Scalar(0);

    //showing the image
    namedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL| CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | CV_GUI_EXPANDED); 
    namedWindow("Rotated Image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL| CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | CV_GUI_EXPANDED); 
    imshow("Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    imshow("Rotated Image", rot_image);
    waitKey(0);

    //convert image 
    Mat img_bw;
    inRange(image, Scalar(1,1,1), Scalar(255,255,255), img_bw);
    imshow("Rotated Image", img_bw);
    waitKey(0);

    //find coordinates
    Mat nonZeroCoordinates;
    findNonZero(img_bw, nonZeroCoordinates);
    RotatedRect rect = minAreaRect(nonZeroCoordinates);
    rect.center = Point(image.cols/2, image.rows/2);

    //get the Rotation Matrix
    Mat M = getRotationMatrix2D(rect.center, 270, 1.0);
    // perform the affine transformation
    warpAffine(image, rot_image, M, image.size(), INTER_CUBIC);

    //displaying the image
    imshow("Rotated Image", rot_image);
    waitKey(0);

    //saving the new image
    imwrite("C:/this/is/a/path/to/a/rotatedImage.png", rot_image);

}
```

That code turns this:

[image: Cropped image of the b/w non-rotated up there]

to this:

[image: enter link description here]

You can take the `rect.center` line out if you're sure your object is already going to be in the center.